# Why I can not access member of generic in swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I can't wrap my head around this. I have the code below. My question is. Why I can not access id in the function compareId (the error, that I am getting is "Value of type 'T.ItemType' has no member 'id'"), but in the function compareIdW I can access the id? Can anyone explain this to me? I will appreciate every help. Thanks

```
import Foundation

protocol ProtoA: Identifiable{
    var id: UUID { get }
}

protocol ProtoB: Identifiable{
    associatedtype ItemType = ProtoA
    var id: UUID { get }
    var arrayOfItems: [ItemType] { get }
}

class M<T:ProtoB>{
    var itemA: T.ItemType?
    init(itemA: T.ItemType?) {
        self.itemA = itemA
    }

    // This does not work
    func compareId(of item: T.ItemType) -> Bool {
        return item.id == self.itemA?.id // when
    }

    // But this does

    func compareIdW<U: ProtoA>(of item: U) -> Bool where U == T.ItemType {
        return item.id == self.itemA?.id
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `T.ItemType` is ambiguous.

At the point that the compiler is looking at your expression all it really knows is that `T.ItemType` is an `associatedType`.  It doesn't really know what properties a particular instance assigned to `ItemType` might have.

Consider this code:

```
struct Marshmallow {
}

struct SmoresStruct : ProtoB {
    typealias ItemType = Marshmallow

    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var arrayOfItems: [Self.ItemType] = Array<Marshmallow>()
}

class SmoresClass : M<SmoresStruct> {
}
```

`SmoresStruct` is a `struct` that satisfies the constraint that it implements `ProtoB`, and it can be used to create `SmoresClass` (a subclass of `class M`) because it satisfies all the constraints you've placed on the generic parameter of `class M`.    But the `ItemType`, `Marshmallow`, is not `Identifiable` so at the point in the implementation of `class M` where you try to imply that `T.ItemType` should have an `id` property, this is one instance where it does not.

You need an additional constraint on your declaration of the `M` Class:

```
class M<T : ProtoB> where T.ItemType : Identifiable {
   ...
}
```

Now if you try to use `Marshmallow` as an `ItemType` you will get:

> Type 'SmoresStruct.ItemType' (aka 'Marshmallow') does not conform to protocol 'Identifiable'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, clear and simple explanation.